# Образование

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Как слово "образование" стало означать учебу? "Образовываться" — это "появляться", то есть, "образование" — это то, что появилось. При чем тут учеба?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И *образование*, и *образовываться* связаны с общеславянским словом **образ**, в др.-рус. языке *образъ* означало «вид, образ, призрак, изображение, икона, пример, способ». Др.-рус. *образъ* восходит к праслав. *оbrаzъ. Слово образ первонач. значило «удар», «след удара» > «то, что вырезано, выбито», затем «нарисованное, вид, форма», «облик», собств. «то, что врезалось в память», «худож. представление».

От сущ. *образъ* «изображение, вид» произведены:

-- с суф. **-ьц-ь** уменьш. *образьць* «бляха, украшение», после утраты слаб. **ь** и прояснения **ь > е** в сильной позиции — соврем. **образец** «форма изготовления чего-либо», «примерный (показательный) экземпляр чего-либо»;

-- с суф. **-ова-ти** (как *пировать*) создан глаг. **образовати** — ст.-сл. «благословить образом, иконой» (устар.), др.-рус. «составить что-либо», «указывать» > соврем. *образовать* «придать соответствующую форму, составить что-либо».

От глаг. *образовати* «составить» с пом. суф. -aниj-e (как *собрание*) произведено сущ. 
**образование1** «действие по этому глаг.». От **образовати** «указывать» > «направлять» > **«обучать»** произведено сущ. **образование2** «процесс усвоения знаний», «просвещение» (в памятниках отмечается с XVI в.). (Цыганенко)